# How to pass method type as parameter?

Tags: delphi, parameter-passing

I would like to pass event types such as TNotifyEvent or TKeyPressEvent.

How do I declare method param to accept these types ?

```
procedure RegisterEventType(AEventType: ???)
```

so that these compile:

```
RegisterEventType(TNotifyEvent)
RegisterEventType(TKeyPressEvent)
```

Point being that `TKeyPressEvent` and `TNotifyEvent` are obviously different:

```
TNotifyEvent = procedure(Sender: TObject) of object;
TKeyPressEvent = procedure(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char) of object;
```

So it's not an instance of event that I want to pass, it's the type.

To give some context this is the implementation:

```
procedure RegisterEventType(AEventType: ???; AFactory: TRedirectFactory)
var
  vTypeInfo: PTypeInfo;
begin
  vTypeInfo := TypeInfo(AEventType);
  Assert(vTypeInfo.Kind = tkMethod);
  vTypeInfo.Name <------ contains string 'TNotifyEvent'

  SetLength(fFactories, Length(fFactories)+1);
  fFactories[High(fFactories)].EventType := vTypeInfo.Name;
  fFactories[High(fFactories)].Factory := AFactory;
end;
```

**context:** TRedirectFactory creates an instance of IEventRedirect which implements TNotifyEvent and is used for redirecting event handlers on forms. There is one implementation for every supported event type (TNotifyEvent, TKeyPressEvent...).
This allows centralised logging and measuring of forms that have lots of code in event handlers.

So the intent is to not pass a string `'TNotifyEvent'` but actual type `TNotifyEvent`.

Comment: `MyProc(aParam:TNotifyEvent )` or are you looking for the other way round.

Comment: Can you show pseudo-code for what the body of your `RegisterEventType` looks like? The best approach will depend on what you want to do with that parameter.

Comment: How about `procedure RegisterEventType(AEvent: PTypeInfo; AFactory: TRedirectFactory);
 ......
RegisterEventType(TypeInfo(TNotifyEvent),nil);
`

Comment: @bummi Yes that's what I use as a workaround

Comment: No easy way to do this. There are meta classes, `class of T`. But nothing like that for procedural types. Perhaps you'll need to use `TRttiType`.

Comment: You might use generic classes, if supported by your version of Delphi, so you could write `TEventTypeRegistrar<TNotifyEvent>.Register(MyFactory);`, but I'm not sure it's an improvement over the `TypeInfo` variant that you already have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like hvd suggested, you can use Generics if your version of Delphi supports that, eg:

```
type
  TEventTypeRegistrar<T> = class
  public
    class procedure Register(AFactory: TRedirectFactory);
  end;
```

```
class procedure TEventTypeRegistrar<T>.Register(AFactory: TRedirectFactory);
var
  vTypeInfo: PTypeInfo;
begin
  vTypeInfo := TypeInfo(T);
  Assert(vTypeInfo.Kind = tkMethod);

  SetLength(fFactories, Length(fFactories)+1);
  fFactories[High(fFactories)].EventType := vTypeInfo.Name;
  fFactories[High(fFactories)].Factory := AFactory;
end;
```

```
TEventTypeRegistrar<TNotifyEvent>.Register(...);
TEventTypeRegistrar<TKeyPressEvent>.Register(...);
```

Alternatively:

```
type
  TEventTypeRegistrar = class
  public
    class procedure Register<T>(AFactory: TRedirectFactory);
  end;
```

```
class procedure TEventTypeRegistrar.Register<T>(AFactory: TRedirectFactory);
var
  vTypeInfo: PTypeInfo;
begin
  vTypeInfo := TypeInfo(T);
  Assert(vTypeInfo.Kind = tkMethod);

  SetLength(fFactories, Length(fFactories)+1);
  fFactories[High(fFactories)].EventType := vTypeInfo.Name;
  fFactories[High(fFactories)].Factory := AFactory;
end;
```

```
TEventTypeRegistrar.Register<TNotifyEvent>(...);
TEventTypeRegistrar.Register<TKeyPressEvent>(...);
```

Comment: And why make the entire class generic instead of just the Register method?

Comment: You could. But what if the Registrar class needs an `Unregister()` method, for instance? Then it makes more sense to specify the Generic parameter once on the class itself instead of on each method individually.

Comment: @Stefan Having a generic class would make it easier to implement the storage for the registry.

Comment: Making the class generic will cause multiple classes with each having its own registry (unless you inherit from a non generic base class with a `class var fFactories` (or making fFactories a global variable *ugh*).